# Using gethostbyname to resolve an IP

Tags: php

I want to code some debug-windows that only shows up when I am visiting the page. I have a DDNS address that contains my IP. This IP is asked on the server. Or lets say it should be asked. But there comes the resolving problem.

I tried to resolve an IP by using:

```
echo gethostbyname("google.com");
```

No matter what domain I use, it always fails and only returns the domain as documented. It returns the IPv4 address or a string containing the unmodified hostname on failure.

I also tried:

```
function getAddrByHost($host, $timeout = 3) {
    $query = "nslookup -timeout=$timeout -retry=1 $host";
    if(preg_match('/\nAddress: (.*)\n/', $query, $matches))
        return trim($matches[1]);
    return $host;
}
echo getAddrByHost("google.com");
```

This one has the same result. Performing `nslookup -timeout=$timeout -retry=1 google.com` in my commandline on my pc works fine. But I need it for a script so this doesn't help me at all :)

I expect a normal IPv4 address.

Does this function need special php.ini settings to run?

My main question is, is this function totally broken?

Comment: Can't you look for the Location header ? `gethostbyname($headers['Location'])`

Comment: and where should the variable `$headers` should come from ? :D

Comment: Yeah the `get_headers` method, but actually testing here, it's not working either! :|

Comment: Can you share your expected output?

Comment: It simply should output an IPv4 address.

Comment: Both work fine (custom func and gethostbyname) on my system for google.com.  Seems like you have a potential connection issue from the user running PHP.

Comment: i dont know... i will check this, give me 1 min

Comment: My original comment wouldn't have applied since you're running a CLI.  Have you tried just running passthru instead of using backticks on $query?  You removed the backticks in your edit, but backticks essentially run it as shell_exec and hide the output.  See what the output is from nslookup when running through php.

Comment: @Devon seems like the port is closed on the testlocation. Changing the server solved it. Obviously you are right.

Comment: DDNS basically works by having a bit of software on your network send your ip address to the service on a regular basis. You could cut out the middle man and write a few lines of code in a cron / scheduled task on your pc to send the IP direct to your webserver

Comment: @Steve ddns is configured in our company-router. so this will be up to date :) and its a customer homepage that gets maintained sometimes. so i dont want to shoot at birds with a tank :D

Comment: Fair enough, and it looks like you solved the issue, so you should probably  post a self answer

Comment: Actually its @Devon who earns this. So if hes so kind to add one, ill accept him :)

Comment: Please do not update question bodies with answer material, nor add [solved] to the title. That is what answer posts and the acceptance system are for.

Comment: Why don't you set a special cookie to enable the debug messages?

Comment: @Alex setting a cookie is obviously the better way to solve this, to be honest, this didnt even came to my mind before. Thx for this hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Be sure to check the ability to connect to port 53 (DNS)
2. You can debug further by trying `passthru('nslookup google.com 2>&1')` from PHP.  This will show the full output from stdout and stderr as it's likely to include some more info.